# The type or namespace name 'KasraDll' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a project that is built in my computer. but when I want create a team build with TFS i am getting this error:

The type or namespace name 'KasraDll' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? )

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the KasraDll into source control? The TFS Build will need a way to resolve the reference to this file. The [TFS Patterns and Practices](http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chapter%203%20-%20Structuring%20Projects%20and%20Solutions%20in%20Source%20Control&referringTitle=Home) discusses checking 3rd Party files into source control.

Alternatively, if this is an assembly you created, you may have it set as an assembly reference (a reference to the built binary), you should have it set as a project reference instead (adding a reference to the project in the solution).